# Access Crashes When Using VBA To Set Bound Combobox RowSource

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I've asked this on UA but wanted to post here as well in the hope someone can help me figure this out.  Also, I'm aware of the evils of using MVFs; this is just something that I want to figure out.

I have a form with a combobox that is bound to a multivalue field.  I want to use VBA to set the RowSource of the combobox.  (Specifically, I want to use the value of another combobox on the form to filter the available choices in the second combobox, but right now I'm just trying to get the RowSource update to work with a static SQL statment.)

If I set the RowSource in the form's Design Mode, then it works as expected.  But as soon as I try to use the exact same value to set the RowSource in VBA, Access crashes.  Here is the code on the After Update event of the 'parent' combobox:

```
Private Sub cboSelRegSet_AfterUpdate()
  Dim strSQL As String
  On Error GoTo Query_Error

  strSQL = "SELECT tblRegulation.ID, tblRegulation.RegulationCode " _
         & "FROM tblRegulation " _
         & "ORDER BY tblRegulation.RegulationCode;"

  MsgBox "Before Filter", vbOKOnly
  Me.cboSelReg.RowSource = strSQL
  MsgBox "After Filter", vbOKOnly
  Me.cboSelReg.Requery
  MsgBox "After Requery", vbOKOnly

ExitNow:
  Exit Sub

Query_Error:
  MsgBox Err.Description
  Resume ExitNow

End Sub
```

If I make "cboSelReg" unbound, then the update works, but since it is no longer bound to an MVF, the user can only select one value which defeats the purpose.

I've also added msgbox prompts to step through the code and it seems to get through the entire subroutine since I get the prompt after the requery.  But as soon as I click OK, Access crashes.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: What did you have as `RowSource` before running the code?  In Access 2010, I can limit the available selections in a combo bound to a multi-value field by adding a `WHERE` clause to the combo's original query.  And that works (on my system) from a VBA procedure in the form's module without crashing Access.

Comment: Hi @HansUp, At first I set the `RowSource` to the full value set from the source table (no `WHERE` clause) by adding it in Design Mode.  Then I removed it in Design Mode, thinking maybe Access didn't like it being set in Design Mode and being set in VBA, but that didn't help.  If I leave the 'child' combobox unbound, then the  `RowSource` part works and it filters the 'child' results as expected.  But the user cannot select multiple values.  As soon as I bind it and try again, it crashes.   I'm using Access 2016, FWIW.  If you are able to get it to work, can you post the VBA you are using?

Comment: I tested the sample db you posted at UA.  It crashes for me, too, after binding cboFramework to Framework_ID.  I can't see a solution.

Comment: Thanks for checking.  I keep hoping it's something small I've missed but it's looking like this is a bug / unhandled exception, and another reason to stay away from MVFs.